# What is auth.authenticate view in laravel 5.2 auth

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

What is the use of `auth.authenticate` view, as there is no file under the auth direcirectory named "authenticate", also what is `loginView` here?

As mentioned in this code:

```
   public function showLoginForm()
    {
        $view = property_exists($this, 'loginView')
                    ? $this->loginView : 'auth.authenticate';

        if (view()->exists($view)) {
            return view($view);
        }

        return view('auth.signin');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the auth trait (`AuthenticatesUsers`), you can overwrite the default view for it. You can overwrite more things like: redirect url when the auth is a success, failure url etc.

So that code can be translated to:

> if the property `loginView` exists then the view `loginView` will be
>   loaded, else `auth.authenticate`
>   if `auth.authenticate` exists then load it else `auth.signin`

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication)

Comment: where can i find a reference for it? Where does auth.authenticate locate to?

Comment: Should be located at `[project_root]\resources\views\auth\signin.blade.php`